How to generically type-annotate a fuction/method parameter to accept any real number type?
I would like to write a generic function that takes an instance of any type that implements all real number operations (such as int, float, fractions.Fraction, or third-party types). I found the numbers.Real ABC which works great for enforcing the type at runtime with a isinstance(x, numbers.Real) check, and all built-in real number numeric types in Python are registered as a virtual subclass of it.
But I found out the hard way that while it works great for run-time checks, it doesn't work well for type annotation purposes because all major type checkers ignore usages of abc.ABC.register. So how do I annotate my parameters which accepts any real numeric type then?
This post in a discussion suggests using the typing.SupportsInt protocol in favor of the numbers.Integral ABC, but in my case I need a replacement for numbers.Real. Also, it only checks if a class implements __int__, not if it supports all integral operations. And something like typing.SupportsReal doesn't exist... Would I just have to define my own protocol that checks for the existence of all real number operation dunder methods (__add__, __sub__, __mul__, __div__, __truediv__, etc...)?

Oh well, python/mypy#3186 contains a lot of background for this problem. Since you already found it, please explain what's unclear/questionable there. I'd recommend to go with a custom Protocol, but only with operations your code actually needs, not all available numeric dunders.

@STerliakov I guess I was just hoping there was some built-in type annotation for "numeric object" that I missed. Thanks for confirming I need to write my own protocol I guess.

What should happen if your function gets passed an instance of complex, or numpy.ndarray? What about decimal.Decimal, which implements incompatible semantics for % and //? You're not going to be able to distinguish these cases with a protocol.

I think the real answer is that you're just screwed, unfortunately.

Depends what you're trying to do. If you want to do z = f(x, y) where x, y and z are the same type, then typing.TypeVar will get you most of the way there (except if you need to use "true" division). If you mean where x and y can be different types, then that's just a minefield. Some types will place nice together, whilst other will just refuse to interact (eg. Fraction and Decimal do not even let you use addition).

@user2357112 Yeah, good point. And the documentation also warns that types could implement a method (causing it to pass the Protocal check) without implementing it, like complex which defines a __float__ that is hard-coded to raise TypeError. I guess I'll just give up on making my class generic and go with hard-coding a Union like typing.Union[int, float, fractions.Fraction].

Related, if not duplicate: How to hint at number *types* (i.e. subclasses of Number) - not numbers themselves?

@InSync Wow, that's a really comprehensive answer that sums up the options . It didn't really tell me anything I didn't already know though. Anyway, I've already gone with using Union[int, float, Fraction] because like that answer said, using typing.Supports* is a bit unreliable. But if you want, you can make that an answer and I'll accept it. Or you could mark this question as a duplicate I guess.

A simple solution would be to do something like this:
Say you're trying to multiply something by 2 and return the product:
def multiply(n):
    product = float(n) * 2
    if product % 1 == 0:
        return int(product)
    else:
        return product

So basically, transform it into a float, do whatever you want to do with it, then check if it's a whole number, if it is then turn it into an integer, if it is not then leave it as it is.
